# Resize batch of numpy images efficiently using multiprocessing python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, multiprocessing

Original numpy array: [10000, 96, 96, 3] (Each 96 * 96 * 3 is an image)

Required output: [10000, 64, 64, 3]

Any code or suggestions needed for resizing using multiprocessing would be helpful

Below is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from skimage.transform import resize

def read_obs(path):
    data = dict(np.load(path))
    return data['observations']

def load_data(data_folder,rollout_number):
        # output array
        obs = np.zeros((10 * 1000, 64, 64, 3))

        i, j  = rollout_number * 10, (rollout_number + 1) * 10

        # loading rollouts from i to j
        file_names = [data_folder + "rollout_" + str(k) + ".npz" for k in range(i,j)]

        #implemented some multi processing for fast loading
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
        obs_list = pool.map(read_obs, file_names)

        # obs_list contains [10(rollouts) * 1000(frames) , 96 , 96 , 3]
        # i want resized output in obs [10(rollouts) * 1000(frames) , 64 , 64 , 3]
        # need help with multiprocessing for resizing

        return obs
```

I have tried skimage.transform.resize and cv2.resize, but they are too slow.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific technical problems, not a place where you dump off your work for others to do. As such, this is off topic. See: [ask/on-topic].

Comment: @AlexanderCécile This is a specific technical problem, and I am expecting answers from someone who came across this. I didn't find clear resources for this issue. I have tried using skimage.transform.resize, cv2.resize but it is too slow.  And yes, I am expecting to save some time at work by asking it here. Any code or suggestions will be appreciated. Can you show me which rule of on-topic is it violating?

Comment: Quick thing before I write another entire comment: Use a context manager to handle pools. They’re very practical.

Comment: `np.load('....npz')` returns a dict like object; no need to wrap it in `dict()`.

Comment: What are your requirements for the quality of the resized images? If `skimage.transform.resize` and `cv2.resize` are too slow for you, you can adjust the interpolation settings. Generally this comes at the cost of quality, but for many applications bilinear interpolation is fine.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to re-implement world models, I ran into the same problem but I just ended up using torchvision's resize method Not exactly sure why it is a lot faster, but processing 1k images took 350ms opposed to 1min for skimage resize approx 180x faster